# Isoperimetric ratio and the boundary of curvature under curve shortening (shrinking) flow

Tags: riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow, gradient-flows

I got stuck by the 3.2 Lemma of **An isoperimetric estimate for the Ricci flow on the two-sphere**, which is collected in [Collected papers on Ricci flow](http://library.lol/main/29f472b9eea6a0145f9540d74409aeba).

As picture below, $L$ is the length of $\Lambda^t$. I think the contrary of Lemma 3.2 is that:

There is a  surface and  $\eta>0$ such that   $\forall E >0$ there is $\Lambda^0$ such that
$$
C_S(\Lambda^t)\le C_S(\Lambda^0)  \tag{1}
$$
and
$$
\int_{\Lambda^t} k^2 dt \le E   \tag{2}
$$
cannot be met simultaneously.

I can't understand the proof of red 2. The Grayson's theorem should be the Theorem 0.1 of [Shortening embedded curves](https://sci-hub.ru/10.2307/1971486). Which state that under curve shortening (shrinking) flow, if the flow has finit time solution, then the curve converges to a point. Otherwise (namely the flow has infinite time solution), the curve converges to geodesic.

But, in Grayson's paper, there is not theory about the decrease of $C_S(\Lambda^t)$  and  the curve shortening flow.

Besides, the Lemma 3.2 seemly be contrary with the red 1.

And, I also try to prove the Lemma 3.2. What I try:

case 1: $(2)$ false, namely, for any $E>0$, there is
$$
\int_{\Lambda^t} k^2 ds >E.
$$
Since the length of $\Lambda^t$ decrease, we have $k^2$ is unbounded on $\Lambda^t$. Namely, the flow has finite time solution. By the Theorem 0.1 of Grayson, the curve convergence to a point, which is contrary with $L\ge \lambda$, where $L$ is the length of $\Lambda^t$.

case 2: $(1)$ false. Since from the red 1, when $(1)$ false, $(2)$ is right. So I don't know how to get the contradiction. (In fact, I spend much time, but fail. I doubt whether my understand is right, since the proof seemly not be complex.)

> [image]